# Java error: cannot find symbol from object array

Tags: java, arrays, object, constructor

I've looked around and tried to solve this issue by recompiling my other classes etc but nothing seems to work.

I have two files, in SensorDataDisplay.java I have the following code:

```
private SensorSim[] sensors;

...

public void runSimulation(double numberOfSensors)  {
  sensors = new SensorSim[numOfSensors];
  int i = 0;

  for(i = 0; i<numOfSensors; i++) {
    sensors[i].SensorSim(sensorNom, sensorErr);
  }
}
```

And then in the same directory I have SensorSim.java compiled into SensorSim.class, the constructor is below.

```
public SensorSim(double n, double d) {
    if (probs == null)
      loadData();
    nominal = n; sd = d;
    rng = new Random();
    running = true;
}
```

This was working when I was just creating a single sensorSim. I recently added the array of sensorSims which is when I got this error:

```
$ javac SensorDataDisplay.java

SensorDataDisplay.java:44: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method SensorSim(double,double)
location: class SensorSim
      sensors[i].SensorSim(sensorNom, sensorErr);
            ^
1 error
```

Looking around I saw that it may have to do with older class files so I removed and recompiled the other files (SensorSim.class). Another possible reason that i read was to do with scope but it looks okay to me, i'm new to Java however. Why might this error may be occurring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You try and run a method called `SensorSim(double, double)` on a `SensorSim` instance (`sensors[i]`), which does not even exist at this point.

If what you meant was creating a `SensorSim` instance at each array element,

```
sensors[i].SensorSim(sensorNom, sensorErr);
```

should become:

```
sensors[i] = new SensorSim(sensorNom, sensorErr);
```

What is more, your `runSimulation()` method takes a `double` as an argument and uses that to size an array (`sensors = new SensorSim[numOfSensors];`) : this `double` will be "downcast" to an `int`.

Comment: Perfect compiled without issue. I'de since changed the double to an int when debugging but hadn't changed my post. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to call a *constructor* like this:

```
sensors[i].SensorSim(sensorNom, sensorErr);
```

That's not how you do it. I suspect you want:

```
sensors[i] = new SensorSim(sensorNom, sensorErr);
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
sensors[i].SensorSim(sensorNom, sensorErr);
```

with

```
sensors[i] = new SensorSim(sensorNom, sensorErr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You get the error because of this line of code:

```
sensors[i].SensorSim(sensorNom, sensorErr);
```

This will work, instead:

```
sensors[i] = new SensorSim(sensorNom, sensorErr);
```

Keep in mind that sensors[i] is like having for example

```
SensorSim s; 
s = new SensorSim(sensorNom, sensorErr);
```